# Ubuntu showing problems in connecting two external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, monitor, external-monitor

I am working with Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell E7240. I have connected two external Dell monitors E2211Hb but they both are not working simultaneously. Yesterday both were working fine and after some time one of start flickering and eventually stopped(showing that no input is received from laptop). Today same problem persists. When I disconnected other monitor, surprisingly the monitor which was showing problem starts working. But anyhow I couldn't get both work simultaneously.

One monitor is connected via VGA to mini DP connection and other monitor is connected via DVI to HDMI connection. The one connected through HDMI was showing flickering problem. Please help me to settle this problem.